# unterminated dollar-quoted string postgress for creating function

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, database-trigger, sql-function

this question might ask many here but I have tried their advice, but it still doesn't work on me, so I am going to ask this
I am trying to create a `function` where to trigger update_at automatically when i update something on tables 
here is my syntax on `.sql` file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i always got error:

```
unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW()"
```

I have tried to change it to `$$` but still doesn't work,
I am using Go for this case with the migration tool called [sql-migrate](https://github.com/rubenv/sql-migrate)

can anyone has a solution for this? I have tried from yesterday and I get really stuck now for this

Comment: Looks like your client treats the semicolon as end-of-statement - and ignores the surrounding quotes. Seems broken.

Comment: did u mean the client broken ? i tried on `psql -c "THAT_SYNTAX" ` it was worked @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: Yes, the client seems broken. The statement is fine. I have seen clients that can't cope with dollar-quoting. But you say it breaks with standard single-quotes, too.

Comment: ok thx for the advice :) @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 0):

It might come from your client, that does not recognize dollar quoting.

A typical workaround is to use regular single quotes. This requires double quoting all embedded single quotes, but fortunately you code has none, so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: i have tired this also before asked this question, i got error like this : `unterminated quoted string at or near "'` when run it again

Comment: on `psql -c `THAT_SYNTAX`` was worked, but on my client got error